# Can some one hack my website using forgot email?

Tags: php, login-control

Today I came to know a wired thing happened in my website that make me tensed. When I put the code `$mail="s.com"` in Forget Email section it show the following error in front end.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
>   in /home/buyurcar/public_html/mywebsite.com/admin/ajax_functions.php on line 81
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/buyurcar/public_html/mywebsite.com/admin/ajax_functions.php on line 83

Does this mean that some one can hack my website through forget password option.
Is this normal or I should worry about this.

Please help I am not good in programming.

Comment: I think mysql query is not up to the mark, your query is missing something.

Comment: Yes, worry about this, especially since you are using the `mysql_*` set of functions. Turn off error reporting in live.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav but my concern is "can some one hack into my website through forget password option" or not if they put some code instead of email in forgot password?

Comment: More than likely you will have an SQL injection issue and your site would likely easily be compromised. You would need to post that code for further examination. You should stop using the `mysql_*` library in favor of `PDO` or `mysqli_`

Comment: `can some one hack into my website through forget password option` <-- can only say if we see the code or try to hack into the site. which one would like to try? warning: the second method is nasty.